# Chrony's "sources with unknown address" in `activity` and `sources -a` when using NTP Pool Servers

Tags: ntp, ip-address, chrony

I found `chronyc`'s `activity` command outputting something like this:

```text
chronyc> activity
200 OK
5 sources online
0 sources offline
0 sources doing burst (return to online)
0 sources doing burst (return to offline)
12 sources with unknown address
```

So I was surprised about "12 sources with unknown address".
As I read that `chronyc -N` and `sources -a` should help to diagnose, I tried that:

```text
chronyc> sources -a
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
=+ host-v22.sap.domain.org       3  10   337   717    -42us[  -75us] +/- 2936us
^? p21.ntp-pool.domain.org       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? p21.ntp-pool.domain.org       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^* p21.ntp-pool.domain.org       2   7   377    57    +74us[  +81us] +/- 2845us
^? p21.ntp-pool.domain.org       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? p21.ntp-pool.domain.org       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? p21.ntp-pool.domain.org       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
...
^? p22.ntp-pool.domain.org       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? p22.ntp-pool.domain.org       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^- p22.ntp-pool.domain.org       2   6   377    45   +107us[ +107us] +/- 2847us
```

(The "domain.org" is fake; actually it's Intranet)

So it seems the "unknown addresses" are from a pool server configuration.
But how can I find out what the problem actually is?

Or is it just a bug in chrony when querying pools?
My guess is that `chronyc` should have displayed the IP addresses instead of the pool names.

The version being used is "chrony-4.1-150400.19.4.x86_64" of SLES15 SP5.